# Find $a, \sigma^2$ s. t. $\sqrt n (Y_n - a) \rightarrow \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of equally distributed independent random variables with $\mathbb P(X_i = 2) = \mathbb P(X_i = -2) = 0.5$. Consider a sequence of random variables $Y_n = {(n^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^3)}^2 - n^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^6$. One asks to find $a$ and $\sigma^2$, s. t. $\sqrt n (Y_n - a) \rightarrow \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ (if they exist).

I managed to show that $Y_n$ converge almost surely to $64$. Now I have no idea how to develop this problem and I would really appreciate if somebody could provide me with some hint or a reference!

Comment: While the law of large numbers gives $(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^3)^2\to0$ a.s., I don't think the limit is also $0$ for $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^6$ (hint: $X_i^2=4$).

Comment: Two more hints: central limit theorem + Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: @nejimban Thank you! I found an error in my calculations: $Y_n \rightarrow 64$ almost surely. Now I am almost sure of it either :)

Comment: $X_i^{2k}$ is a constant for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$

Comment: @d.k.o. I know it, thanks.